# Can Bundler be configured to install gems rdoc?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rdoc

I use [bdoc](https://github.com/manalang/bdoc) (with [hanna](https://github.com/mislav/hanna) for formatting) as a quick way of looking at the rdoc documentation for the gems installed on my system. However, because bundler does not install rdoc when installing gems, I'm constantly having to generate them manually whenever I start using a new gem, or update an existing one.

Does anyone know if there's a way of configuring bundler to get it to install rdoc when installing gems to avoid me having to do it manually? I can't see any mention of this in the bundler source, nor in the [config manual](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-config.1.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you use rvm, try "rvm rdocs generate ..."

Answer (score 1):

My first answer is wrong, there is a feature request for bundle on this and an invitations from the developer to implement this option.

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/383

Answer (score -1):

bundler is concerned with an application's environmental dependencies.
rdoc is not an environment dependency, but a developer resource tool.

(continue to) use `gem rdoc gemname`

Comment: This is not an answer.  It might be a comment.